# How to ensure a file that an user uploads was initially downloaded from the system

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For security purposes we want to ensure the user is uploading a file that was initially downloaded from the system. The file type is excel and application is in.NET CORE.

Solution I am thinking is to add a custom property(say author) to the file. We have the byte array and would like to append a byte array that would add that custom property.
Ideally doing the above update before return the file
return File(fileData, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);

Comment: Do you expect the user to upload the exact same version of the file that was previously downloaded? Or can the user download a file, make some changes, and then upload the modified version? What exact problem are you trying to solve here? At first glance might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We do except the user to download the template, fill it out and re-upload it. So in essence the uploaded file needs to have some kind of metadata that indicates it was initially generated by the system.

Comment: The file type is excel. I don't know if a code example is necessary for the question I am asking. I am asking for a solution that helps identify if the filed out excel template (that is being uploaded) was initially downloaded from the system.

Comment: I'm very sorry, as far as I know, asp.net core can't solve your problem. You can use the office interop  to perform attribute operations on the excel file, but this can't fully meet your requirements, because the attribute you set is also can be modified by user .

Comment: I first tried to set the custom author attribute suggested by you. However, this attribute can also be modified by the user, so it cannot be the metadata that indicates it was initially generated by the system, and asp.net core can't directly modify the properties of the excel file, and then I try to query a specific file based on the unmodifiable creation time, but the creation time of the file is not the same when uploading and downloading. The same, it cannot use this as a sign of the same file to indicate it was initially generated by the system.